# How math is working in python (Linear Regression)

Tags: python, math, linear-regression

I want to find slope in python by converting maths in python code. In math slop formula is -

```
m = Σ(x-x̄)*(y -ȳ)/ Σ(x-x)^2
```

but in python, it is calculated by-

```
m = (np.sum(x*y) - n*x_mean * y_mean) / (np.sum(x*x) - (n * x_mean * x_mean))
```

I am not sure how we are doing this formula is derived in python. Can you please help me?

I have attached the math formula as Python formula in an image for better understanding. Please check that as well.

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMzOM.jpg

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: How could an `n` just apear in your formula? You will have to do the math properly before bringing it into Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving numerator and denominator

## Σ(x-x̄)*(y -ȳ)

= Σ(xy-x̄y-xȳ + x̄ȳ)

= Σxy -Σx̄y -Σxȳ +Σx̄ȳ

= Σxy -x̄Σy -ȳΣx +nx̄ȳ

= Σxy -nx̄ȳ -nx̄ȳ +nx̄ȳ

= Σxy - nx̄ȳ

## Σ(x-x̄)^2

= Σ(x*x- 2xx̄ + x̄*x̄)

= Σ(x*x)- Σ(2xx̄) + Σ(x̄*x̄)

= Σ(x*x)- 2x̄Σ(x) + n*x̄*x̄

= Σ(x*x)- 2nx̄x̄ + n*x̄*x̄

= Σ(x*x)- n*x̄*x̄

m = (Σxy - nx̄ȳ) / (Σ(x*x)- n*x̄*x̄)

which in python is

```
m = (np.sum(x*y) - n*x_mean * y_mean) / (np.sum(x*x) - (n * x_mean * x_mean))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the cross product in linear regression is a piece-wise multiplication, wherein, each component in the vector is multiplied only with corresponding components in the other vector. You are assuming typical algebraic expansion, involving multiply each component with every other component, which doesn't work.

so,

```
Σ(x-x̄)*(y -ȳ) != Σ(xy-x̄y-xȳ + x̄ȳ)

Σ(x-x̄)*(y -ȳ) = Σ(xy -x̄ȳ) = Σxy -Σx̄ȳ = Σxy - nx̄ȳ
```

similarly,

```
Σ(x-x̄)*(x -x̄) != Σ(xx-x̄x-xx̄ + x̄x̄)

Σ(x-x̄)*(x -x̄) = Σ(xx -x̄x̄) = Σxx -Σx̄x̄  = Σxx - nx̄x̄
```